# Torsors for discrete groups in the etale topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, cohomology, etale-cohomology, torsors

Let $S$ be a smooth variety over $\mathbb C$ or a smooth quasi-projective integral scheme over  Spec $\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $G$ be an (abstract) discrete group. For instance, $G =\mathbb{Z}^n$ or $G$ a finite index torsionfree subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. I want to exclude finite groups, but also infinite  products of finite groups. (Actually, I am only interested in non-abelian torsionfree Fuchsian groups.)

Is every $G$-torsor over $S$ trivial for the etale topology on $S$? If not, what are some interesting examples?

Comment: Am I right in assuming that such things are classified by (continuous?) homomorphisms from the etale fundamental group of $S$ to $G$? If so, there should be plenty of examples as soon as $G$ has finite subgroups, which for example $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has several of.

Comment: Good point. I edited the question.

Comment: The OP does specify that $G$ should be torsionfree.  I think the OP wants somebody to say, a torsor over a regular base for the 'etale topology necessarily factors through a finite subgroup of the structure group.

Comment: How do you define torsor?